# How to fit all widgets inside a canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program in Python that shows me all the connected devices in a network. All these connected devices will be drawn into a Canvas and will give me certain buttons and options (also inside the canvas).

These devices and their options are **placed** inside the Canvas using `.place()`. I do this so that I can place all devices in the canvas by stating their x and y coords and fit everything nicely in a grid-esc pattern. (See the image below).

My problem is that if their are more than a number of devices found in the network, the canvas won't resize to fit all these rectangles, lines and buttons inside of it.

Is there any easy way or a function that says to the canvas to resize relative to all the items inside it?

[image]

Comment: ***"says to the canvas to resize relative to all the items inside it"***: This is the default behavior of [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm). [Edit] your question and explain in detail, **why** do you need to use `Canvas`?

Comment: I thought the canvas widget was the perfect widget for drawing stuff, like rectangles and lines. (See the image for a rough sketch of what the devices would look like if there are **4** of them in the network).

Comment: You can use `canvas.bbox()` to find the bounding box of all the items in canvas and then calculate the required size of the canvas in order to show all the items.

Comment: This is what I was looking for @acw1668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comment @acw1668 posted, I used `.bbox` to do the following:

```py
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox('all')
canvas.config(width=x2, height=y2)
```

This made it all fit nicely!